# No two-monitor option in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

Recently "up"graded to 18.04 from 16.04, and the system isn't recognizing I have two monitors.  I'd REALLY love to "down"grade back to 16, but that's likely going to be near impossible.

Comment: What have you checked in the settings to make sure it is only seeing one monitor?  Is the Display in settings set to Mirror?  What video card do you have?  What is your system?  Have you installed or reinstalled the correct video driver?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1203722/edit) your question and add more details of your system and things that you have tried.

Comment: Q: What have you checked in the settings to make sure it is only seeing one monitor? 
A: Settings > Devices > Displays.  There is nothing indicating more than one monitor is in use.  Screen only lists Orientation, Resolution, and Nightlight. 

Q: Is the Display in settings set to Mirror? 
A: N/A, no such option; if "mirror" even listed, I would modify it.  

Q: What video card do you have? 
A: Hardware Lister not showing it; NVidia

Q: What is your system?
A: OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 

Q: Have you installed or reinstalled the correct video driver?
A: Not yet, lemme see about that, thx

Comment: 07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] [1002:7183] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])